# Writing a PHP API and an Android app

Tags: php, android, api, zend-framework2

I have a shop project written with Zend Framework 2 and now I want to write an app for this project. I'm new to this whole Android thing (I wrote a few test apps, but no big project like this). So at this moment I'm planning the "app-project" but i didn't find that much till yet.

I have to write the API in PHP and the complete Android app, so I just wanted to ask if someone can show me some good tutorials/sites etc to get more information for this (there are some big topics I'd like to know like security with the JSON communication etc).

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Maybe you would like to look into https://github.com/victorjonsson/PHP-Rocker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building your API in PHP assess first which framework you want to use. I've had success using Yii to build a quick REST JSON API. After getting to grips with Yii this article explains in detail the process of building a REST API: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/

You have a few choices in terms of authentication and securing your API. Firstly make sure all data is sent over https otherwise your efforts to secure your API are wasted because anyone listening on your network can read requests/responses in plaintext. Look at using OAuth or a HMAC pattern similar to Amazon web services for authenticating requests. Here's a great article on the latter: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/

Comment: I'm actually using Zend Framework 2. but many thanks to the article, that helps a lot!